# Http11Protocol not found

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat

I have a simple empty Gradle Tomcat project in my Eclipse. Got error define below when run:

```
Task :tomcatRun
    Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 365 days
        for: CN=localhost, OU=Test, O=Test, C=US
    
    Warning:
    The -storepass option is specified multiple times. All except the last one will be ignored.
    Protocol handler instantiation failed
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    ...
```

Why `Http11Protocol` not found? How to fix this problem?

The whole content of build.gradle:

```
plugins 
{
    id 'com.bmuschko.tomcat' version '2.5'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
    id 'java-library'
}
    
repositories 
{
    jcenter()
}

    
dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '9.0.39'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
}
    

tomcat {
    httpPort = 8080
    enableSSL = true
    contextPath = '/dynamic-web-gradle'
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
}
```